# Excel VBA to set RadioButton GroupNames

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a quiz. It works well for the part I have but is a bit lengthy. The RadioButtons I am using are set at the start through the Properties window. I have a "Reset" CommandButton that I am using to clear the quiz.

```
 '  Question Block 1
 '  THIS method does work
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.Enabled = True
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton2.Enabled = True
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton3.Enabled = True
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton4.Enabled = True
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.Value = False
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton2.Value = False
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton3.Value = False
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton4.Value = False

 '  Question Block 1 (Alternate Method)
 '  THIS method does NOT work
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.GroupName = "Q1"
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton2.GroupName = "Q1"
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton3.GroupName = "Q1"
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton4.GroupName = "Q1"
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton.GroupName("Q1").Enabled = True
 ActiveSheet.OptionButton.GroupName("Q1").Value = False
```

The first block of code works fine. The second one does not. What am I doing wrong with trying to assign the RadioButtons to a group in this manner? I've tried numerous approaches and most end with error messages saying object does not support this property or method, method or member not found, object required and on and on. Scratching my head.  --Edited I am NOT using this in a UserForm. The RadioButtons are just placed on the Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that seems to work really well for my purposes. I was looking to do this by GroupNames property but as long as it works there are a number of ways to solve any problem. Hope someone else can benefit from this code.

```
' Defines OptionButtons as Objects
Dim OptBtn As OLEObject

'  Re-Enables RadioButtons
For Each OptBtn In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(OptBtn.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
        OptBtn.Object.Enabled = True
    End If
Next

'  Resets RadioButtons to False (removes the dot)
For Each OptBtn In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(OptBtn.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
        OptBtn.Object.Value = False
    End If
Next
```